# Grails 3 - achieving customization of template in a way it was possible with _form.gsp in version 2

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-3.0.9, grails-3.1

I am relatively new to Grails and I am little disappointed with the way _form.gsp removed with field plugin in Grails 3. _form.gsp seemed to be good time saving option when we need to customize views with Bootsrap or materialize.

Now with grails 3, install-templates does not create _form.gsp. As per [this](https://grails-fields-plugin.github.io/grails-fields/guide/single.html#customizingFieldRendering) documentation, we can achieve customization by creating _wrapper.gsp, _widget.gsp etc under view/_fields/default directory. But I am not able to find the example of such custom GSPs.

Also, let's say if I customize all the four GSPs (_wrapper.gsp, _widget.gsp, _displayWrapper.gsp, _displayWidget.gsp) will it generate actual code when we run generate-view command? I mean will it replace, f:all, f:table etc tag with actual code? If not then there is quite amount of work to do I guess. Because after we are confident about our domain class and tested all CRUD operation, we run generate-view command for creating all the domain specific GSPs. Then in most cases, we need to do some changes according to our requirement, like re-ordering the fields, hiding some of the fields

So in conclusion I have two goals:

1. Customizing default templates and start developing.
2. When I run generate-view, I do not want f:all, f:table etc abstract tags. I need actual fields in place so that I can customize generated views of domain.

If any one has achieved this, then please share the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Grails 3 comes with the fields plugin by default. The templates used in Grails 2.x have been replaced in full. So, your goal 2. will be hard to achieve with Grails 3 it seems.

However, here is a helpful blog which explains how you can adjust some of the fields templates by replacing them in your project: http://blog.anorakgirl.co.uk/2016/01/what-the-f-is-ftable/

Similar to the description provided, you can place a modified _list.gsp template in folder in

```
/grails-app/views/templates/_fields/
```

Hope it helps.